# Getting Images From Array Change Randomly

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, object

I am developing one app in that app get the images from NSArray and store it into ImageView that image view scroll the vertically and each an every page has single image.

I want to display random images when app start each an every time.all images shuffle every time.

I tried this one.

```
    UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 490)];


    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];


    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];


    NSArray *imageArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"image1",@"image2",@"image3",@"image4",@"image5", nil];

    for( i=0; i< [imageArray count];i++)
    {

        int i=arc4random()%[imageArray count];   // For Shuffle the images

        NSString *imageName=[imageArray objectAtIndex:i];


        NSString *fullImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",imageName];


        int padding=25;


       CGRect imageViewFrame=CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*i+padding, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width-2*padding, scrollView.frame.size.height);


        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];

        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fullImageName]];


        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    }

    CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*[imageArray count], scrollView.frame.size.height);


    [scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewSize];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Images Displayed Properly but not change randomly.
Help me Out this
thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for the sake of code clarity - replace your local "i" variable's name (the one you declare within the for loop).

Comment: there seems nothing wrong with your code, just try what @Stavash suggests, may be that is the problem

Comment: images randomly generate now but the one image display 2 times in scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm has a serious flaw in that you don't ensure that you haven't chosen the same index twice. Also, for the sake of writing code properly, replace "i" with something else:

```
int randIdx=arc4random()%[imageArray count];   // For Shuffle the images
NSString *imageName=[imageArray objectAtIndex:randIdx];
```

Comment: @Stavash sir images randomly generate now but the one image display 2 times in scroll.

Comment: Because for every iteration of your loop, you're selecting a random number in the exact same range, so why wouldn't there be duplicates? How about using an NSMutableSet to store indexes you haven't used and removing them as you go along?

Comment: i don't no what happening can you post the code to solve that issue.

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow is not to supply code for people who aren't familiar with programming concepts. I think that I gave you more than enough ideas and directions to proceed. Make an effort to implement this on your own and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try something different name

```
int randNo=arc4random()%[imageArray count];
```